# Foreach Iterator Behavioral Difference in PHP 5.2.0 versus PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, foreach, iterator

```
$test = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);


foreach($test as $element)
{
    echo $element;        
    $element = next($test);         
    echo $element;
}
```

This produces the output "122334455" in PHP 5.2.0
The output "13243545" is produced in PHP 5.3.3

How do I reproduce the output of 5.2.0 in 5.3.3 most efficiently by means of controlling the iterator?

This may be a bug as the iterator works in 5.2 inside the foreach, but not in 5.3's foreach.

Comment: Which output do you desire, "122334455" or "13243545"?

Comment: I desire "122334455". I need a means to control the iterator in the foreach. I use to have that control with next() and prev(), but it's effect is temporary until the next iteration in the loop for 5.3.3.

Comment: Why would you use this behavior in the first place? You really shouldn't be changing the iterator *while* you loop over it.

Comment: @RafeKettler It doesn't matter the why. I just need it. I know what I'm asking. It's something very specific. I need a means to control the iterator in the foreach.

Comment: @FinalForm if there's a safe and portable way to do what you want to do then the why matters

Comment: @RafeKettler It would greatly simplify things for me if there was a way.

Comment: If it doesn't work as you like, I would skip the `foreach` and manage the array's iterator entirely on your own.

Comment: @DavidHarkness That's what I ended up having to do. I hope this bug is fixed. The inconsistency in behavior with this next() method in the different version is sorta annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug related with PHP. You can use a more explanatory "for" loop:

```
$c = count($test);

for($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    echo $test[$i];
    if(isset($test[$i+1])) {
        echo $test[$i+1];
    } else {
        echo $test[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is "somewhat" acceptable. Any of you guys out there have a better solution?

Comment: Implemented. What I had to do. Thanks. Not exactly what I'm looking for, but I guess I have to do it this way. I gave you credit.

Comment: I hope the people working on PHP fix this bug. It's quite annoying to have a foreach supercede control in regards to iterables.

Comment: It looks like foreach and next are now using the same array pointer in 5.3 resulting in the array pointer being advanced twice.

Answer (score 1):

My try:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($test as $element)
{
    echo $element;
    if (isset($test[$i])) {      
        $element = $test[$i];         
        echo $element;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

This also works but is memory inefficient :

```
$test  = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$test2 = $test;

foreach($test as $element)
{
    echo $element;        
    $element = next($test2);         
    echo $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what you are asking.. anyway:

```
echo array_shift($test);
foreach($test as $v) {
 echo $v.$v;
}
```

prints: 122334455 as asked in the original question

Comment: I'm asking for a means to control the iterator in an array when it's being iterated over using a foreach(). Your solution is more concerning stacks, popping and shifting which isn't what I'm looking for. It's not controlling the iterator while keeping the data in the array. A means to traverse the array while it's being iterated. Sorry if that sounds confusing.

Comment: @finalform: then you should totally cahnge your question